# Running second docker daemon with --bridge=none deletes docker0

Tags: docker

The first daemon runs with almost default config. I am trying to start a second docker daemon with different config, following the instructions in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#run-multiple-daemons.

Full command, and the complete debug logs.

```
sudo dockerd  -D \
    -g /home/$USER/dockerd/g \
    --exec-root=/home/$USER/dockerd/e  \
    --iptables=false \
    --ip-masq=false \
    --bridge=none \
    -H unix:///home/$USER/dockerd/docker.sock \
    -p /home/$USER/dockerd/docker.pid

DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 999                 
DEBU[0000] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/home/jayaprabhakar/dockerd/docker.sock) 
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 2810 
WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
DEBU[0000] containerd: read past events                  count=0
DEBU[0000] containerd: grpc api on /home/jayaprabhakar/dockerd/e/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock 
DEBU[0000] containerd: supervisor running                cpus=2 memory=3951 runtime=docker-runc runtimeArgs=[] stateDir=/home/jayaprabhakar/dockerd/e/libcontainerd/containerd
DEBU[0000] libcontainerd: containerd health check returned error: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable 
DEBU[0001] Using default logging driver json-file       
DEBU[0001] Golang's threads limit set to 56430          
INFO[0001] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: aufs 
DEBU[0001] Using graph driver aufs                      
DEBU[0001] Max Concurrent Downloads: 3                  
DEBU[0001] Max Concurrent Uploads: 5                    
INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit 
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period 
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime 
WARN[0001] mountpoint for pids not found                
INFO[0001] Loading containers: start.                   
DEBU[0001] Option Experimental: false                   
DEBU[0001] Option DefaultDriver: bridge                 
DEBU[0001] Option DefaultNetwork: bridge                
INFO[0001] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0001] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[0001] Docker daemon                                 commit=c6d412e graphdriver=aufs version=17.03.1-ce
DEBU[0001] Registering routers                          
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/checkpoints 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/checkpoints 
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /containers/{name}/checkpoints/{checkpoint} 
DEBU[0001] Registering HEAD, /containers/{name:.*}/archive 
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/json            
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/export 
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/changes 
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/json  
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/top   
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/logs  
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/stats 
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/attach/ws 
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /exec/{id:.*}/json          
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/archive 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/create         
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/kill 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/pause 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/unpause 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/restart 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/start 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/stop 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/wait 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/resize 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/attach 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/copy 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/exec 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start      
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/resize     
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/rename 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/update 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /containers/prune          
DEBU[0001] Registering PUT, /containers/{name:.*}/archive 
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}    
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /images/json                
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /images/search              
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /images/get                 
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/get       
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/history   
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/json      
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /commit                    
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /images/load               
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /images/create             
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/push     
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/tag      
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /images/prune              
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}        
DEBU[0001] Registering OPTIONS, /{anyroute:.*}          
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /_ping                      
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /events                     
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /info                       
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /version                    
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /system/df                  
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /auth                      
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /volumes                    
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /volumes/{name:.*}          
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /volumes/create            
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /volumes/prune             
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /volumes/{name:.*}       
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /build                     
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /swarm/init                
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /swarm/join                
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /swarm/leave               
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /swarm                      
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /swarm/unlockkey            
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /swarm/update              
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /swarm/unlock              
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /services                   
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /services/{id}              
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /services/create           
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /services/{id}/update      
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /services/{id}           
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /services/{id}/logs         
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /nodes                      
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /nodes/{id}                 
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /nodes/{id}              
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /nodes/{id}/update         
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /tasks                      
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /tasks/{id}                 
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /secrets                    
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /secrets/create            
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /secrets/{id}            
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /secrets/{id}               
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /secrets/{id}/update       
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /plugins                    
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /plugins/{name:.*}/json     
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /plugins/privileges         
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /plugins/{name:.*}       
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/enable  
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/disable 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /plugins/pull              
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/push    
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/upgrade 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/set     
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /plugins/create            
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /networks                   
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /networks/                  
DEBU[0001] Registering GET, /networks/{id:.+}           
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /networks/create           
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /networks/{id:.*}/connect  
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /networks/{id:.*}/disconnect 
DEBU[0001] Registering POST, /networks/prune            
DEBU[0001] Registering DELETE, /networks/{id:.*}        
INFO[0001] API listen on /home/jayaprabhakar/dockerd/docker.sock
```

Now, the default bridge docker0 used by the first daemon is missing. So, when I start a container trying to connect to the default daemon, I get this error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint romantic_allen
on network bridge: adding interface veth5b99b4e to bridge docker0 failed: 
could not find bridge docker0: route ip+net: no such network interface.
```

Did I miss any flag that should have been present, that deleted the default daemon's network and bridge?

Comment: It said u must configure each Docker daemon. Did you try that?

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't. That could be a probable cause of the issue. I'll try to configure the default.

Comment: You might give a summary as answer if that works.